# Looping through an array using AlpineJS returns no results

Tags: javascript, arrays, alpine.js

I'm attempting to loop through an array using AlpineJS, but for the life of me, I can't get any output.

I'm hoping someone that is more familiar with AlpineJS may be able to assist.

Thanks in advance.

And here's the code:

```
<script>
function alpineInstance() {
  return {
    books: []
  }
}
</script>

<div 
x-data="alpineInstance()"
x-init="fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Alpine')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => books = data)">
  <template x-for="(book, index) in books" :key="index">
    <div x-text="book.items.volumeInfo.title"></div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've got the wrong idea of what kind of data this API returns. Copy the URL you're passing to the `fetch` function and paste it into the browser. Hopefully, you'll see pretty quickly that this endpoint doesn't return an array, it returns an object!

```js
function alpineInstance() {
  return {
    // we'll set our data to hold an object
    bookResponse: {}
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div x-data="alpineInstance()" x-init="fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Alpine')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => bookResponse = data)">
    <!-- instead of mapping over an object, which will throw an error, we'll map over bookResponse.items !-->
    <template x-for="(item, index) in bookResponse.items" :key="index">
    <div x-text="item.volumeInfo.title"></div>
  </template>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Brendan! You're absolutely right in your response and I'm very grateful for your help. Thank you.